# "diverges to $1$"

Tags: terminology

$\newcommand{\logit}{\operatorname{logit}}$

A series may "diverge to $\infty$" or "diverge to $-\infty$"; a product may "diverge to $\infty$" or "diverge to $0$".

**postscript in response to comments:**

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$, it is standard to say that the product $\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ "diverges to $0$".  The product diverges to $0$ iff the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\log a_i$ diverges to $-\infty$.

Why do we not say of a series that it "converges to $+\infty$" rather than that it "diverges to $+\infty$"?  The object $+\infty$ is an absorbing element with respect to addition: $+\infty+x=+\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.  If we don't allow this kind of arithmetic, we still say that if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i$ diverges to $+\infty$, then $x+\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i$ diverges to $+\infty$, for $x\in\mathbb R$.  The same applies to all other instances in this question: If $\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ diverges to $0$, then $x\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ diverges to $0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R^+$.  Similarly in the example below, once the conditional probability given the data is $1$, adding a finite amount of additional information leaves it at $1$.

**end of postscript**

Now suppose we have either of two coins $A$ and $B$ and tossing $A$ gives $H$ more often than tossing $B$.  Then
$$
\begin{align}
\logit \Pr(A\mid\text{outcome of first $n$ tosses})
& = \log\frac{\Pr(A \mid \text{outcome of first $n$ tosses)}}{\Pr(B \mid \text{outcome of first $n$ tosses})} \\[10pt]
& = \logit \Pr(A) + \log\frac{\Pr(\text{outcome}\mid A)}{\Pr(\text{outcome}\mid B)}. 
\end{align}
$$
If we get $H$ every time, then $\logit\Pr(A\mid\text{outcome})\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and if we get $T$ every time, then $\logit\Pr(A\mid\text{outcome})\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Clearly it makes sense to say that in the former case $\Pr(A\mid\text{outcome})$ "diverges to $1$", since you're approaching an absorbing boundary.  By "absorbing", I mean that if you were to actually reach $0$ or $1$, you would be stuck there and could not get away from it.

My **question** is simply whether this phrase "diverges to $1$" occurs in that strange place called Reality, in particular in published books, journal articles, and the like.

**Usage note:** It appears that some non-statisticians may be unfamiliar with the term "logit".  The first syllable is pronounced with a long "o" as in "low" and the "g" is like the "j" in "jet".  It's defined as
$$
\logit p = \log \frac{p}{1-p}.
$$
Clearly $\logit p\to+\infty$ as $p\uparrow 1$ and $\logit p \to-\infty$ as $p\downarrow 0$, and $\logit(1/2) = 0$, and $\logit(p) = -\logit(1-p)$.

Comment: Why not say "converges to $1$"?

Comment: @AlexBecker : Because you're heading toward an absorbing boundary.  Once you're at $0$ or $1$, you can't get away from it.

Comment: I've never heard anyone talk about a product diverging to 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Now you have.  It's a standard thing.

Comment: A [quick search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22diverge+to+1%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C39&as_sdtp=) indicates that the phrase *"diverge  to $1$"* is used here an there.

Comment: Then again, after looking through a few, some of these appear to be false positive.  Perhaps this phrase isn't in common usage after all.

Comment: Infinite products diverge to $0$, not converge to $0$.  Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) this is done "in order to obtain results analogous to those for infinite sums".  The basic idea is that an infinite product is defined using its logarithm, which is an infinite sum, and if the infinite product goes to $0$ that means the infinite sum of logarithms goes to $-\infty$, which is a divergent limit.